# How to Center an Android Label

Tags: android

been trying to center my android label. Should I use action bar for this?

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TurboMileage">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is my strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Turbo Mileage</string>
```

Comment: Show us the design `xml`

Comment: Why did you put two useless XML files as the code? The strings XML and manifest XML are useless. Show us the UI related code on your attempts to centre the label. Then we can help you

Comment: @Noah I think he may want to center the app name in the toolbar.  Which would explain why he thinks these are the right xml files-  the toolbar label is in the application tab.  But yes, he'll probably need to make a custom toolbar to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use theme with NoActionBar and create your toolbar:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivSetting"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivBack"
            android:layout_width="?actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```